# Custom post type filter is being applied to all of my posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I've created a filter to alter `the_title` hook in one of my custom post types (thanks Chip Bennett for the snippet). The function is supposed to tell Wordpress to call the title from a custom field (`_location`) within my custom post type page.

The problem is that all of my pages and posts in Wordpress are displaying 'No Title'. Instead, I want plain 'ole posts to display their titles normally, then I want my custom post title to display the contents from my custom field.

Here's the code that filters the titles:

```
function change_title ( $title ) { 
if ( !'events' == get_post_type() ) { 
    return $title; 
} else { 
    global $post; 
    $custom = ( get_post_custom( $post->ID ) ? get_post_custom( $post->ID ) : false ); 
    $custom_title = ( isset( $custom['_location'][0] ) ? $custom['_location'][0] : '(No Title)' ); 
    return $custom_title; 
} 

} 
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title' );
```

Here's my entire functions.php file:

```
<?php


// Registers the new post type and taxonomy
function wpt_event_posttype() {
register_post_type( 'events',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom Widgets' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Widget' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add Custom Widget' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Custom Widget' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Custom Widgets' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'Add New Custom Widgets' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Custom Widgets' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Custom Widgets' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No custom widgets found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No custom widgets found in trash' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'custom_fields' ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array("slug" => "events"), // Permalinks format
        'menu_position' => 99,
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_events_metaboxes'
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_event_posttype' );



// Add the Custom Widgets Title Meta Box
function add_events_metaboxes() {
add_meta_box('wpt_events_location', 'Custom Widget Title', 'wpt_events_location', 'events', 'normal', 'high');

// Add the Page Template Assignments Meta Box
add_meta_box('pagetemplate', 'Page Template Assignments', 'pagetemplate', 'events', 'normal', 'high');

// Add the Post Assignments Meta Box
add_meta_box('postassignments', 'Post Assignments', 'postassignments', 'events', 'normal', 'high');

// Add the Additional Filters Meta Box
add_meta_box('additionalfilters', 'Additional Filters', 'additionalfilters', 'events', 'normal', 'high');
}


// The Callback for Custom Widget Title Metabox
function wpt_events_location() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the title data if its already been entered
$boxtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true);
// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="_location" value="' . $boxtitle  . '" class="widefat" />';
}


// The Callback for Page Template Assignmets Metabox
function pagetemplate() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pagetemplatemeta_noncename" id="pagetemplate_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the title data if its already been entered
$boxtitle2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_template', true);
// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="page_template" value="' . $boxtitle2  . '" class="widefat" />';
}


// The Callback for Post Assignmets Metabox
function postassignments() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="postassignmentsmeta_noncename" id="postassignments_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the title data if its already been entered
$boxtitle3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-assign', true);
// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="post_assign" value="' . $boxtitle3  . '" class="widefat" />';
}


// The Callback for Additional Filters Metabox
function additionalfilters() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="additionalfiltersmeta_noncename" id="additionalfilters_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the title data if its already been entered
$boxtitle4 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'additional_filters', true);
// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="additional_filters" value="' . $boxtitle4  . '" class="widefat" />';
 }


// Save the Metabox Data
function wpt_save_events_meta($post_id, $post) {
// verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
// because save_post can be triggered at other times
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
return $post->ID;
}
// Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
    return $post->ID;
// OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
// We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.
$events_meta['_location'] = $_POST['_location'];
// Add values of $events_meta as custom fields
foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
    if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
    $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    }
    if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields




add_filter( 'manage_edit-events_columns', 'my_edit_events_columns' ) ;

function my_edit_events_columns( $columns ) {

$columns = array(
    'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'title' => __( 'Custom Widget Title' ),
    'page_assign' => __( 'Page Template Assignments' ),
    'post_assign' => __( 'Post Assignments' ),
    'additional' => __( 'Additional Filters' ),
    'date' => __( 'Date' )

);

return $columns;
}




add_action( 'manage_events_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_events_columns', 10, 2 );

function my_manage_events_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
global $post;

switch( $column ) {

    /* If displaying the 'duration' column. */
    case 'page_assign' :

        /* Get the post meta. */
        $page_assign = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'page_assign', true );

        /* If no duration is found, output a default message. */
        if ( empty( $page_assign ) )
            echo __( 'Unknown' );

        /* If there is a duration, append 'minutes' to the text string. */
        else
            printf( __( '%s minutes' ), $page_assign );

        break;

    /* If displaying the 'duration' column. */
    case 'post_assign' :

        /* Get the post meta. */
        $post_assign = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_assign', true );

        /* If no duration is found, output a default message. */
        if ( empty( $post_assign ) )
            echo __( 'Unknown' );

        /* If there is a duration, append 'minutes' to the text string. */
        else
            printf( __( '%s minutes' ), $post_assign );

        break;  




    /* If displaying the 'genre' column. */
    case 'additional' :

        /* Get the genres for the post. */
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'additional' );

        /* If terms were found. */
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {

            $out = array();

            /* Loop through each term, linking to the 'edit posts' page for the specific term. */
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => $post->post_type, 'additional' => $term->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
                    esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'additional', 'display' ) )
                );
            }

            /* Join the terms, separating them with a comma. */
            echo join( ', ', $out );
        }

        /* If no terms were found, output a default message. */
        else {
            _e( 'No Additional Filters' );
        }

        break;

    /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
    default :
        break;
}
}


function change_title ( $title ) {  
global $post;  
if ( !'events' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {  
    return $title;  
} else {  
    $custom = ( get_post_custom( $post->ID ) ? get_post_custom( $post->ID ) : false );  
    $custom_title = ( isset( $custom['_location'][0] ) ? $custom['_location'][0] : '(No Title)' );  
    return $custom_title;  
}  

}  
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to [**`get_post_type()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) needs to be passed the `$post` object, which you don't globalize until later. Try globalizing the `$post` object earlier. Also, try using `foo != bar` instead of `! foo == bar`:

```
function change_title ( $title ) { 
    global $post; 
    if ( 'events' == get_post_type( $post ) ) { 
        $custom = ( get_post_custom( $post->ID ) ? get_post_custom( $post->ID ) : false ); 
        $custom_title = ( isset( $custom['_location'][0] ) ? $custom['_location'][0] : '(No Title)' ); 
        return $custom_title; 
    } else { 
        return $title; 
    } 

} 
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title' );
```

#### Edit

Also, to ease of troubleshooting, I would recommend writing your conditional in the *affirmative* with respect to your custom post type, i.e. `if ( 'events' == get_post_type( $post ) )`, rather than `if ( 'events' != get_post_type( $post ) )`. The former will only *ever* return true for your post type; the latter will return true *always except* for your post type.

Comment: Hi Chip, I got this snippet from one of your answers.  Thanks for the snippet. I tried the answer you posted above and all my posts still show "no title".  Maybe I'm posting the wrong labels - in this case "events" is my custom post name and the custom field is "_location". Did I insert those labels correctly?

Comment: See updated answer. I made another change to your conditional.

Comment: And one more update, to reconfigure your `if/else` handling.

Comment: Hi Chip, it worked.....you may want to update the snippet from the related post you have here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/custom-post-type-set-post-title-equal-to-a-custom-post-type-field. You could also write a blog post on that one. Not too much out there, but I know people would love to read it.

Comment: Also, I read your profile and noticed you're in ST. Louis. What suburb are you from? I just moved from South City to the Phoenix, AZ area. Take care.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I updated the answer in that post. Also: we're in north county. :)